# After installing python with brew, I get an error with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I am using OSX (latest version, 10.9.5), a new Macbook Pro. Tried to install python with brew:

```
$ brew install python
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/python-2.7.8_1.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.8_1.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Pouring python-2.7.8_1.mavericks.bottle.2.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Setuptools and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip install --upgrade setuptools
  pip install --upgrade pip

You can install Python packages with
  pip install <package>

They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Press ENTER or type command to continue


See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

.app bundles were installed.
Run `brew linkapps` to symlink these to /Applications.
Press ENTER or type command to continue

==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packa
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install --force --verbose --install-scripts=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1/bin --install-lib=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packa
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_1: 4776 files, 76M
```

Then I try to run pip and get an error:

```
$ pip list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing pip by using easy_install? Like this:

```
$sudo easy_install pip
...
$pip -V
$pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

That should work (I've tried and it works on my MacBook).
Hope it helps!